# Currently have css code on my html page. I am trying to move the code to css page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move css code from html page to css page.
When I move my code, some of the function is not working. 
I cannot figure out why, the code is from W3school.

Previous and next button works, but there is no box. So I assume first part of CSS code is not working.

-------------------CSS-------------------------------

```
a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px 16px;
        }
            a:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
                color: black;
            }
        .previous {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            color: black;
        }
        .next {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }
```

-------------------html-------------------------------

```
    <div>
        <a href="Index" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
        <a href="LibraryTour" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you share your LINK element tag and your HEAD tag?